# Truffle test not working when I add migration.js

Tags: solidity, testrpc, ganache

I have written javascript tests that run fine with `truffle test ./test/Token.js`

However, when I have the following:

```
var UTO = artifacts.require("./uto.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(UTO);
};
```

Then I get the following error:

> UTO contract constructor expected 6 arguments, received 0

The error itself is fine, it needs arguments. However, I am wondering why this is happening, because my test script sets these arguments:

```
before(async function() {

      // deploy contract with parameters for testing
      contract = await C.new(company, _token_eth, _name, _symbol, _decimals, _percentToHold);
  });
```

I can comment out the deployer and everything works fine.. so why is the truffle command triggering the deploy outside of the test script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations scripts are always run before each unit test it doesn't matter if you already deploy the contracts before each test.

One option is to have separate 'network' in your `truffle.js` and decide what to do in the script using the network parameter.

```
var UTO = artifacts.require("./uto.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  if (network === 'development') {
    deployer.deploy(UTO, "dummy", 1000, ...); // <-- dummy params
  } else if (network === 'unittest') {
    // Do not deploy contracts, each test should deploy them by itself
  }
};
```